# JQuery adding "d-none" class not reflected when focused on another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to hide on section of my page to show a "loading" spinner. To do this, I just use jquery to add class "d-none" and remove class "d-none from whichever needs to be hidden/shown.

The function:

```html
function toggleWaiting(divName, waiting) {
var $div = $("#" + divName);

if (waiting == true) {
    $div.find(".divSpinner").removeClass("d-none");
    $div.find(".divContent").addClass("d-none");

}
else {
    $div.find(".divSpinner").addClass("d-none");
    $div.find(".divContent").removeClass("d-none");
}

}
```

The function works perfectly when I am focused on the tab, or just when Chrome is opened with this tab as the current viewable one. However, when I go to another tab, and the function to toggle the hidden/shown is called, the content is visible but the spinner is as well.

I am mostly wondering if there is an issue with the way I am doing this, or if there is a gotcha with jQuery I didn't know about? The function does work if I am focused on the tab.

Edit: included full function

Comment: You need to post a complete example, including the assignment of `$div`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update, I still have no idea what the issue was. It wasn't present in firefox though, only chrome. My resolution was instead of ".addClass('d-none');" I did ".show()" and ".hide()".